# COM type mismatch in .net addin for MS Excel VBE

Tags: vb.net, excel, vbe, netoffice, vba

I've been trying to build the example located here:
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx

The only difference to the posting is that I'm trying to use the NetOffice COM interop libraries instead of the recommended private interop libraries.  I can build the basic addin on the above link and load it as a VBE addin (after registering it and adding the reg keys as per the link).

I can't extend it to create a tool window as per this link:
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012017.aspx

I get a COM type mismatch error which I can't figure out.  I can however create the toolwindow from VBA when the addin is loaded which makes me think that the toolwindow class implementation is fine.  My example VBA code which can create an instance of the toolwindow is:

```
Public Sub example()

    Dim doc As Object
    Dim wnd As Object
    Dim wndGuid As String
    Dim progId As String
    Dim caption As String
    caption = "A Caption"

    wndGuid = "{e80c0630-a44c-44ad-86b5-61d8bf664d42}"
    progId = "MyVbaAddin.UserControlHost"

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wnd = .Windows.Item(caption)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If wnd Is Nothing Then

            Set wnd = .Windows.CreateToolWindow(.AddIns(1), _
                                                progId, _
                                                caption, _
                                                wndGuid, _
                                                doc)

        End If

        wnd.Visible = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Its not reasonable to post my entire solution in this question but I have uploaded it to GitHub:
https://github.com/rossknudsen/VbaAddin

The NetOffice dev thinks there may be a problem with his code, but I'm not convinced.  I've imported the NetOffice source to aid debugging though.

Comment: By the way I am running this on Windows 7x64 with Office 2010 x64.  If anyone has any success with other OS/Office that would be great.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a problem in the NetOffice code in the way it handles ref/out parameters which are not initialised.  The error I was getting was related to 'DocObj' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.windows.createtoolwindow.aspx) being Null.  If you initialise the value of this parameter and pass it in, the method works.  The problem is that the call creates a new instance of the document and assigns that to DocObj.  I'm pretty sure I updated the code on GitHub so you can see my implementation.  Its a nasty workaround which I hope someday to fix properly.

Comment: See also: https://netoffice.codeplex.com/workitem/20295